# JQuery make div fade back in if its already fading out

Tags: jquery

```
$('#slider').hover(function()
{
    $('#LayerHover').fadeTo(400, 0.4);
}, function()
{
    $('#LayerHover').fadeOut(400);
});
```

This functions just like u expect the code to work, but when you hover over it and out and in etc. at a fast pace the fading will get buggy because its still finishing its previous fadein/fadeout calls. How do you cancel the "old calls"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cancel queued animations with .stop(). For example:

```
$('#slider').hover(function(){
    $('#LayerHover').stop(true,true).fadeTo(400, 0.4);
}, function(){
    $('#LayerHover').stop(true,true).fadeOut(400);
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: Happy to help, and I'm glad you were able to finish up! :)